# Querying a massive WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sitemap

I am generating a sitemap xml and I am using query_posts() on 25mil posts.

My query exceeds my 400m memory limit around 10k posts. Is there a technique that can fix this?

I just tried doing recursion but that didn't work either (I just realized the php file still runs during each recursing haha) but here's my code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require('../../wp/wp-blog-header.php');
include 'src/SitemapPHP/Sitemap.php';
use SitemapPHP\Sitemap;
$sitemap = new Sitemap('http://www.example.com');
$sitemap->setPath('../xmls/');

$offset = 0;

function parsePosts($offset, $sitemap, $posts = null)
{
    if($posts == null){
        $posts = query_posts('post_type=services&posts_per_page=10000&offset='.$offset);
    }

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp();
        $count++;
        $sitemap->addItem('/services-view/' . $post->post_name);
    endforeach;

    $offset += $count;
    echo $offset;

    if($count == 10000) {
        parsePosts($offset, $sitemap);
    }
}

parsePosts($offset, $sitemap);

$sitemap->createSitemapIndex('http://www.example.com/', 'Today');
```

**Edit, I am also getting this error when the query fails: an error occurred while processing this directive**

Comment: There are plenty of plugins that create sitemap.xml for you.  Is there a reason why you are trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: No. You cannot perform a query on 25 million rows when you only have 400MB of memory available. This will need to be split into sections, and die() after selecting X amount of rows.

Comment: Sitemaps are basicly a xml file i think you can just do it with writing the appropriate xml tag to the file while looping the records on db

Comment: Does this apply?:
http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/10/seo-and-web-development-pros-and-cons-of-sitemap-xml/ 
"By rule, a sitemap.xml file is limited to 50,000 URLs. Last year, Google announced that the sitemap.xml file must be no larger than 50MB for it to be submitted to its Webmaster Tools service."

Comment: @wiredniko not really reinventing the wheel, this is like 10 lines of code. The plugins use all my memory too.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Feel stupid for saying this but how would I do this in my script?